# An error occurred (StatementTimeoutException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: Request timed out

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds

Hi I am trying to run a database query like this using rds client

```
def execute_transaction_query(sql):
            response = rds_client.execute_statement(
            secretArn=AURORA_DB_CREDS_ARN,
            resourceArn=AURORA_DB_ARN,
            database=AURORA_DB_NAME,
            sql=sql,
            continueAfterTimeout=True
        )
```

but after around 40 seconds getting error like

**An error occurred (StatementTimeoutException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: Request timed out**

Till now I tried  **continueAfterTimeout=True** and in boto3 instance

```
rds_client = boto3.client('rds-data', config=botocore.client.Config(
                                         connect_timeout=350,
                                         read_timeout=350,
                                         region_name=REGION,
                                         retries={"max_attempts": 1}
                                     ))
```

still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `execute_statement` not waiting till execution of Query.

RDS data API does not support RDS `serverless` V2. So anytime AWS deprecate RDS Data API. Better go with `psycopg2` in case of `postgres SQL`